# Image Transform as a Field

Tags: image-transforms

I was just checking out the [AP insights case study](https://craftcms.com/news/ap-vector-case-study):
I came across the LiveView Editor screenshot. I see an inline Image Transform Crop field. What is the method to add this crop field ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably just a drop down that sets the crop position setting in the image transform parameter string.

See this: https://craftcms.com/docs/image-transforms#defining-transforms-in-your-templates

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the link! any thoughts on how best to create it? Does the following 'position' attribute accept multiple values for crop position? `{% set thumb = {
    mode: 'crop',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    quality: 75,
    position: 'top-center'
} %}`

Comment: You might need to adjust, but something like this ```{% set cropPosition  = block.imageCropPositionField %}
{% set imageParams = {mode: 'crop', width: 100, height: 100, quality: 75, position: cropPosition} %}
{% set image = block.imageAsset.first() %}
{% if image %}
    <img src="{{ image.url(imageParams) }}">
{% endif %}```

Answer (score 1):

The content builder is very nice. I implemented this code in my project:

```
{% for image in content.image %}
    {% set imageTransform = { 
        width: 1000, 
        height: 700, 
        mode: 'crop', 
        position: content.focalpoint 
    } %}
    <img src="{{ image.getUrl(imageTransform) }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks to: http://craftcookbook.net/recipes/120